# Cannot connect the skin file in head

Tags: head, skin

I'm is beginner in magento.
I try to connect the library jquery-ui, but fail!
.
Paths to the my custom topic:

```
/app/design/frontend/alokuteshop/default/

/skin/frontend/alokuteshop/default/
```

I edit the file local.xml

Path: `/app/design/frontend/alokuteshop/default/layout/local.xml`

Adding:

```
<! - JQuery UI Including ->
<default>
   <reference name = "head">
       <action method = "addItem"><type> skin_js </ type>
              <script> js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js</ script>
        </ action>
    < / reference>
</ default>
<! - / JQuery UI including ->
```

File jquery-ui.min.js is really exist where indicated: `/skin/frontend/alokuteshop/default/js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js`

But magento look for it in the base:

```
 /skin/frontend/**base**/default/js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js
```

And of course not found and display an error to the console.

What is the problem? Tell me please!

I tried to put the library in the root directory and load js through "addJs" (js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js)
It worked:

```
<action method = "addJs"><script>lib/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js</ script></ action>
```

But this is not an option!

I still need to connect another files at this theme. But it is impossible!

What to do?..

Answer (score 0):

There may be **some issues at local.xml**.

- The code which you write that has some space issue  after staring
  `<script>` and before *`js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js`* .**`<script>
  js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js</ script>`**

**so,your code could be :**

```
<default>
   <reference name ="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/lib/jquery-ui.min.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</ default>
```

- Also,you need to check,your  package name should be  `alokuteshop`
  and **skin/images**  folder  name is  **default**.